# How to merge dates between 2 locations using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate, grouping

TIA for any assistance towards this problem, I am rather new to SQL/SSMS.

I would like to understand how I can create date rows for 1 location based on another. For example, I have the following table:

```
ClientFK | LocationFK | Month     | Sales
---------|------------|-----------|-------
15       |1           |2019-04-01 | $100
15       |2           |2019-04-01 | $50
15       |2           |2019-03-01 | $30
15       |2           |2019-02-01 | $20
```

How can I create rows in location 1 in which location 2 had sales? The output would look like this:

```
ClientFK | LocationFK | Month     | Sales
---------|------------|-----------|-------
15       |1           |2019-04-01 | $100
15       |1           |2019-03-01 | $0
15       |1           |2019-02-01 | $0
15       |2           |2019-04-01 | $50
15       |2           |2019-03-01 | $30
15       |2           |2019-02-01 | $20
```

My goal is to make this dynamic, so I'm not trying to work with this specific client/location, it is just an example. Ideally this should work for any client/location combo.

Again, I'm rather new to this, and wasn't sure how to best ask this question. Any advice on how to clarify what I'm asking would be much appreciated as well. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create twelve rows with month per location?

Comment: Not necessarily, I think I could do that. I'd like to only create rows for every month grouped under 1 client. So this client has 3 months, I would like BOTH locations to have rows for those months. Does that make more sense? Thanks btw

Comment: I thought maybe I could make a CTE of months for the client and join back to get what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to go about that, and if there are better solutions out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all months for all locations and all clients.

```
with AvailableDates as(
  select distinct [Month] from MonthlySales
),
Locations as(
  select distinct LocationFk from MonthlySales
),
Clients as(
  select distinct ClientFk from MonthlySales
)
select c.ClientFk, l.LocationFk, ad.Month, IsNull(ms.Sales,0) as Sales 
from Locations l
left join AvailableDates ad on 1=1
left join clients c on 1=1
left join MonthlySales ms on 
  l.LocationFk=ms.LocationFk 
  and c.ClientFk = ms.ClientFk 
  and ad.Month = ms.Month
order by  locationFK, Month desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a  way to go about with this. First find out all of the unique months for Location2.

Then carterisan prod with the Client1 data.

After that you have all of the records for Client1 and Client2 in the carteisan prod block, which would left join with the data and set up the sales=0 for those missing months data.

```
with loc2_data
  as (select distinct month
        from tbl
       where locationfk=2 
         and ClientFK=15
      )
     ,cartesian_prod 
      (
     select a.ClientFK,a.LocationFK,b.Month
       from tbl a
       join loc2_data b
         on 1=1 
      where a.locationfk=1
        and a.ClientFK=15
       )
select a.ClientFK,a.LocationFK,a.Month,isnull(v.Sales,0) as sales
  from cartesian_prod a
left join tbl v
     on a.ClientFK=v.ClientFK
    and a.LocationFK=v.LocationFK
    and a.Month=v.Month
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer George! This definitely sets me in the right direction. Any way to make this dynamic, so it'll work for any number of clients/locations? I should've thought of explaining this, but wanted to keep my example simple. I will update the question.

Comment: If you want an even spread of rows then then you would wan to remove the where clause in loc2_data block and also in the cartesian_prod block. Rest of the stuff you can keep it intact